# Loading images slowly when using download.aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net, download

We try to implement a download.aspx to control our source such as images for specific clients. we use the buffering method in download.aspx.cs. The code is showed below:

```
using (var fs = new FileStream(_path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    Response.BufferOutput = false;   // to prevent buffering 
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int bytesRead = 0;
    if (_file.Extension == ".pdf")
    {
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" + _file.Name);
    }
    else
    {
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + _file.Name);
    }
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", _file.Length.ToString());
    Response.ContentType = ReturnExtension(_file.Extension.ToLower());

    while ((bytesRead = fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
    {
        Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }
}
```

It works well when downloading a single files. However, in our situation, we are try to load about twenty images at the same time. It become extremely slow. The following is the captured screen:-

[image]

We can't find out the reasons. We would like to know it is a practical method to control files or there are the other better way to achieve it.

Comment: can't you use static servicing?

Comment: Have you tried stepping through this code to see which line takes the longest to execute? Also, try the browser debugging tools (network tab - F12 in Internet Explorer, CTRL+SHIFT+J in Chrome) to see if there are any other resources that are holding up the download.

Comment: To Terric: Ya. I have used chrome to investigate the execution time. The most time is wasted on waiting server's response. The problem may be due to server side problem.

Comment: To Steve: Static servicing? You mean web service?

Comment: @Gary, I think Steve is asking why you don't just have the images in a folder on your web server so your code doesn't have to write them out to a stream every time they're requested. If you need to talk to someone who has commented on your posts, putting "@" in front of their name will ensure that they receive a notification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with the above response. However if this is the route you "have to go". you could have a look at the following.

You are using a asp.net Page, rather go the Handler route, you cut out a lot of the asp.net life cycle, and this will help reduce your images load time.

[Second have a look at Asynchronous HTTP Handler.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227433%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

You can also look at caching the response output which will help improve the performance.
[read this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y96218s9%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

I hope some of this information helps.

Comment: Thanks for the useful information. I may take a look and try it.

Answer (score 0):

Asp.net has a limited number of worker threads. When you do something like this, you are increasing the load on those threads many fold.

It is best to let IIS deal with static content.

What should have been one file request, now is at least 17 requests from your screenshot. 
This load will slow down your server significantly.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the problem. Since we need to control source, we need to find out the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used it, but the [HttpModule](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ihttpmodule.aspx) class may give you a way to let IIS serve your files statically, while giving you programmatic control of access to those files:

```
public class AccessControlModule : IHttpModule
{
    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.BeginRequest +=
            (s, e) =>
            {
                if (!AccessPermitted(context))
                    context.Response.Redirect(AccessDeniedUrl);

                // Otherwise, IIS will serve the file as normal
            };
    }

    //...
}
```

---

```
<httpModules>
   <add name="AccessControlModule" type="MyNamespace.AccessControlModule" />
</httpModules>
```

See [here](http://www.netfxharmonics.com/2007/08/Real-World-HttpModule-Examples) for some samples.